# How to get `animateWithDuration` to start from same point every time it is called, iOS, Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I'm not sure if I'm missing something or just haven't calculated the `dx` `dy` offset correctly, but I have a UILabel positioned at `x: 0 y:0`  and am using the `animateWithDuration` function to add a UILabel to a view with a bit of animation.

However every time it is called it just moves another `dy: 100` from where the animation stopped last.

Here is my code:

```
//UILabel variable - Global variable if you must know.
var informationView: UILabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 400, height: 400))

//Function to present UILabel with animation.
func animate(){
    UILabel.animateWithDuration(0.5,
            delay: 0.0,
            usingSpringWithDamping: 0.3,
            initialSpringVelocity: 3.0,
            options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseInOut,
            animations: ({
                self.informationView.frame.offset(dx: 0, dy: 100)}),
            completion: nil)
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You have to reset the frame's origin back to (0,0) before animating again, otherwise you'll just be adding another offset of 100 to the current origin's y value. You could do that with another animation or just set it explicitly to jump it back.

Comment: Excellent, thank you. Cannot believe I didn't think of doing this.